# C# Threads, WaitHandle.WaitAll

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is that possible not not block  winForm using WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles) but just set another thread which will fire when get complate signal from WaitHandle.WaitAll?

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use `WaitHandle.WaitAll`. There are a couple of problems with this approach.

- There is a 64 handle limit.
- It cannot be used on an STA thread.
- It promotes patterns that depend on the creation of multiple `WaitHandle` instances which obviously consume resource.

Instead, I typically use the `CountdownEvent` class when I want to wait on multiple events. Now, the problem you will have with that is that it still requires you to call `Wait` on some thread which is exactly what you are trying to avoid. The standard mechanism to avoid making a blocking call is to use the `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method. But, unfortunately that takes a `WaitHandle` and `CountdownEvent` does not inherit from that class.

The solution is to create your own `CountdownWaitHandle` class that can be used in the `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method. This approach will allow you to specify a callback delegate that will be executed once the `WaitHandle` is signaled.

Here is the most basic implemenation for the `CountdownWaitHandle` class. You will have to add all of the necessary harding code yourself, but this will get you started.

```
public class CountdownWaitHandle : WaitHandle
{
    private int m_Count = 0;
    private ManualResetEvent m_Event = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public CountdownWaitHandle(int initialCount)
    {
        m_Count = initialCount;
    }

    public void AddCount()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref m_Count);
    }

    public void Signal()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_Count) == 0)
        {
            m_Event.Set();
        }
    }

    public override bool WaitOne()
    {
        return m_Event.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

The idea here is that instead of using many different `WaitHandle` instances you use a single `CountdownWaitHandle` instance. Initialize the instance with the desired count and then call `Signal` to decrement the count. Once the count gets to zero the `WaitHandle` will go into the signaled state. So instead of calling `Set` on multiple `WaitHandle` instances and blocking with `WaitHandle.WaitAll` you now call `Signal` on this one instance and block by calling `WaitOne`. And again, you can push off the blocking call to the thread pool by using `TheadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` which will invoke a callback when the `WaitHandle` is signaled.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `WaitAll` in a background thread, then call `BeginInvoke` to move back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).  Using this you can set the event when your thread has finished, and any other thread can either wait on this event, or check to see if it is in the signalled state.

```
ManualResetEvent ev = new ManualReserEvent();
while(Users["user428547"].AcceptanceRate == 0)
{
   // this might take a long time
};
ev.Set(); // done, he accepted an answer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could start another thread yourself, and call `WaitHandle.WaitAll` yourself on that thread?  If you are not starting too many other threads, this should work fine.

Comment: no cos then i got WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA thread is not supported

Comment: Can't you make the new thread an MTA thread? MSDN social seems to have a discussion about this here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/eefc0160-987c-47e1-a41b-bbae96726ec4/